# How can I validate Zip Code in visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, validation

I'm having a requirement where I need to validate a ZIP Code when a state is entered.Say suppose if a state is entered with a ZIP code of 12345 then it should check whether the zip code is exactly matching with the state or not and if doesn't matches then it should throw an error. The data was stored in USPS system.

Comment: do you have the list of state and its associated zipCode with you

Comment: You need to have somewhere zip code vs Sate stored  using which you can validate the zip code entered for the selected state, probably you can store that combination in separate custom object and fetch details from their and validate.

Comment: yes state vszipcode was stored in USPS. Need to get data from it

Comment: Then you can write validation rule to validate zipcode, also think about zipcode can be 5 or 9 digit or kind of 99999-9999 format

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **USPS Web Tools Service** to achieve this. Please refer to their online [Web Tool Kit Development Guide](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/general-api-developer-guide.htm), there is a method available to check the State based on the State.

You can make a REST call with required parameters, in your Apex to validate the zip code as entered in VF Page.

**Test Request #3**

This API is used to find the City and State associated with a ZIP Code.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup
&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxx"><ZipCode ID= "0">
<Zip5>90210</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CityStateLookupResponse><ZipCode ID="0"><Zip5>90210</Zip5>
<City>BEVERLY HILLS</City><State>CA</State></ZipCode>
</CityStateLookupResponse>
```

Please note you have to register to use their service.

> How to call the USPS Service to validate Zip code from Apex

First, register for `USPS Web Tools` and get the UserID. Then add `http://production.shippingapis.com` to your remote site settings before testing the class.

```
public class TestUSPSAPI {
    public void validateZip(String zipCode){
        String userID = 'XXXXXXX';
        String reqXML = '<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="'+userID+'"><ZipCode ID= "0"><Zip5>'+zipCode+'</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>';
        String endpoint = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=';
        endpoint = endpoint+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(reqXML,'UTF-8');
        HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
        System.debug('Endpoint URL: '+ request.getEndPoint());
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        Http p=new Http();
        HttpResponse response=p.send(request);
        String resXML=response.getBody();
        System.debug('resXML :'+ resXML);
        Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        docx.load(resXML);
        Dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getRootElement();
        String state = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode', null).getChildElement('State', null).getText();
        System.debug('State :'+ state);
    }
}
```

You can test the class from developer console as below .

```
TestUSPSAPI uspsAPI = new TestUSPSAPI();
uspsAPI.validateZip('12345');
```

Comment: Can you give me a example on how to call a rest api as I'm not aware of calling a webservice api. It would be of great help

Comment: Please check my Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: VF page][image: Custom Settings]I have made use of Custom Settings for storing the zip and state mappings. I have also written VF page and apex class for validation logic.

Here is the Code

```
public with sharing class ZIPCodeValidateController
{
    public String State {get;set;}
    public String ZipCode{get;set;}

    public Map<String,String>StateZIPcodeMappings = new Map<String,String>();

    public ZIPCodeValidateController()
    {
        List<StateZIPcodeMappings__c> stateZipCodeMappingList = StateZIPcodeMappings__c.getall().values();

      for( StateZIPcodeMappings__c sz : stateZipCodeMappingList )
      {
          StateZIPcodeMappings.put(sz.Zip__c,sz.name);
      }

    }

    public void validateZIPcode()
    {    String actualState= '';
        if(ZipCode!=null && ZipCode!='')
        {
           actualState = StateZIPcodeMappings.get(ZipCode);
        system.debug('StateZIPcodeMappings++++'+StateZIPcodeMappings);
        system.debug('state++++'+actualState);
        system.debug('ZipCode++++'+ZipCode);
        }
        if(String.isBlank(State))
        {

        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter State Value'));
        }
        if(String.isBlank(ZipCode))
        {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter ZipCode Value'));
        }
        if(actualState!=null && actualState!='' )
        {
            if(actualState.equalsIgnoreCase(State))
            {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'State and Zip Code matched'));
            }
            else
            {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'State and Zip Code not matched'));
            }
        }



    }

}
```